# Strange behaviour for Dates in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a sheet with a column populated with dates (exported using a Google API, all at the same time) however when I use an ISDATE to check (after I noticed some irregularities in my data) a bunch of them show up FALSE, but most of them show up TRUE.

Below is a small snippet of the data, the only difference is that the ones returning false appear to be left-aligned for some reason while the ones that return true are right-aligned (unfortunately, not able to replicate this in the table below).

| Date Value | ISDATE Check |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Sept 2019 | FALSE |
| 1 Sept 2019 | FALSE |
| 1 Sept 2019 | FALSE |
| 1 Sept 2019 | FALSE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |
| 31 Aug 2019 | TRUE |

I'm baffled, but what I need is a way to convert them all to day/month/year, I was using =TO_DATE() which worked for all the values where the ISDATE check returned TRUE but just repeated the date in the same format where it was FALSE (so 1 Sept 2019, after the TO_DATE returned 1 Sept 2019 rather than 01/09/2019)

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Or have any idea how to get around it?

Here is the [data I am working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PdLcx60aKpjeG6Ba5xsW9V9J-dK2ZLO6P3SVwRT6i5w/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abreviation of september is sep, not sept. So replace sept by sep each time if necessary.

Comment: That's the bugger, dunno why I didn't pick up on that. I wonder why Google exports it like that? :|